# No image is loading in Jekyll

Tags: javascript, imgur

I built a slider based carousel using jQuery. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmeanog1/5/) is a fiddle that describes it. This page will be a post in my website, and has the code:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Jammu And Kashmir GIFs"
---

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">






      <style>
   #slider
   {
     width: 80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
  #custom-handle {
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 120% ;
  }
  </style>

  <script>
    $( function() {
            $( "#slider" ).slider({
                max: 88
            });

        var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );

        $( "#slider" ).slider({

        create: function() {

        var slide_number = Math.floor(parseInt($(this).slider("value"))/5.55555) ;
        $("#para").text(slide_number) ;
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( (Number("value")+1900)+'' ) );
        $('.carousel').carousel(slide_number) ;
        },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var curr_val = parseInt(ui.value) ;
        var slide_number = Math.floor(parseInt(ui.value)/5.55555) ;
        $("#para").text(slide_number) ;
        handle.text( (Number(ui.value)+1911)+'' );

        if(curr_val<5)
            $('.carousel').carousel(0) ;
        else if(curr_val<10)
            $('.carousel').carousel(1) ;
        else if(curr_val<15)
            $('.carousel').carousel(2) ;
        else if(curr_val<20)
            $('.carousel').carousel(3) ;
        else if(curr_val<25)
            $('.carousel').carousel(4) ;
        else if(curr_val<30)
            $('.carousel').carousel(5) ;
        else if(curr_val<35)
            $('.carousel').carousel(6) ;
        else if(curr_val<40)
            $('.carousel').carousel(7) ;
        else if(curr_val<45)
            $('.carousel').carousel(8) ;
        else if(curr_val<50)
            $('.carousel').carousel(9) ;
        else if(curr_val<55)
            $('.carousel').carousel(10) ;
        else if(curr_val<60)
            $('.carousel').carousel(11) ;
        else if(curr_val<65)
            $('.carousel').carousel(12) ;
        else if(curr_val<70)
            $('.carousel').carousel(13) ;
        else if(curr_val<75)
            $('.carousel').carousel(14) ;
        else if(curr_val<80)
            $('.carousel').carousel(15) ;
        else if(curr_val<85)
            $('.carousel').carousel(16) ;
        else if(curr_val<90)
            $('.carousel').carousel(17) ;

        }
        });
    } );
    </script>    
</head>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" >
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>

  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" style="width:50%; height:50%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/pRN7Dzr.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZvImrY7.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/a9nSour.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/K4VusMr.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/gWJj3dI.jpg" alt="Fifth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/cGKWNfv.jpg" alt="Sixth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/tlzMIxH.jpg" alt="Seventh slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/EliUAqd.jpg" alt="Eighth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/5ob7uGp.jpg" alt="Ninth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/tSBB02F.jpg" alt="Tenth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/ccP2bbO.jpg" alt="Eleventh slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/OUWiXCy.jpg" alt="Twelfth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/D3GfCuy.jpg" alt="Thirteenth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/Rd7dZsf.jpg" alt="Fourteenth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/DCv9eVW.jpg" alt="Fifteenth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/yDu3Xrv.jpg" alt="Sixteenth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/0GrtUdy.jpg" alt="Seventeenth slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.imgur.com/sMtT2Tu.jpg" alt="Eighteenth slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
    <script>
        $(function(){
          $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel();
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div>


</div>
<div id="slider">
    <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle">

    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

The problem that I face is that when I load up the page locally through `jekyll` the page doesn't load all the images of the slider. Sometimes it shows only some of the images, other times a single image, and for the rest, no image at all.

**Specifications:**
`_config.yml`:

```
title: Your awesome title
email: your-email@example.com
description: >- 
baseurl: "" 
url: "" 
twitter_username: jekyllrb
github_username:  jekyll
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
```

I want to make the site working. Moreover, I want to know why does this not work, and what is the inner working of jekyll that stops it from working this way.

Comment: A few questions:

What does the layout `post` apply to this page? Does that have anything wrapping it that would potentially invalidate some of the HTML you have on this page (usually layouts are wrapped by headers/footers that include the essential elements like html and head tags)?

Also, have you looked at the output HTML by building the site locally? Does the output for this page match what you're expecting to get? I've seen issues before where HTML can get parsed as a string if it's indented depending on certain parser settings.

Comment: Any code repository ?

Comment: @MaxGardner No, there is nothing in the layout `post` that could invalidate the HTML of this page. See the `post.html` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/esdhfx1c/). I tested by replacing `{{content}}` by this code, and it ran perfectly. Secondly, I tried opening the built version of the post, and it comes out to be working fine, when opened locally (without using jekyll). Would you mind clarifying what has happened here?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Actually there is, but I'm doing all this locally, so I don't think that would help.

Comment: Oi @MaxGardner! Putting `markdown = "0"` inside every `img` tag did the work. It tells Jekyll that the tag is to be treated as raw HTML. Now, if this tag was not being treated as raw HTML, then how could it show me the `alt` text of the `img` tag? This doesn't quite make sense. Any help?

Comment: @Mooncrater Ah yes, the `markdown="0"` syntax is from the [Kramdown processor](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-blocks). Is this file saved as HTML? That should allow you to avoid MD processing for it. Regarding the issue with images not always displaying, it could be as simple as a syntax error in the HTML (example - I see an unpaired closing `div` in that JS Fiddle you sent with the `post.html` content). I'd recommend you consolidate your `head` sections into `post.html` and ensure this file is just the carousel content to eliminate that as a potential cause.